# lldb python handle process crash or killed

Tags: python, debugging, lldb

I want to do something when a process is crash or killed in a python script.
However I can't find anyway to know when a process is stop by lldb.

I've tried to catch a SIGKILL signal but no use.

```
import lldb
import signal
def debug(sig, frame):
    print "stop!\n"
def listen():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGKILL, debug)  # Register handler
```

I've find that we can use this to handle a breakpoint hit, but it can't deal with my situation.

```
def breakpoint_function_wrapper(frame, bp_loc, dict):
```

Anyone has some solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a little sample program in the lldb python examples that shows how to handle process events using the lldb library:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/process_events.py

That might help get you started.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. The demo is really helpful.